# Why getline not accepting input

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

From top of the code is working but surprisingly the last cin.get(con) doesn't wait for input and terminate the program with accepting any input, why this is happening so, kindly guide me what is wrong with my code -

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct country
{
char country[30];
char capital[30];
float income;
};

void main()
{
  country c[3];
  clrscr();
  for( int i=0; i<3 ; i++)
  {
    cout << "\n Country's name : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(c[i].country, 30);

    cout << "\n Country's capital :";
    cin.getline(c[i].capital,30);

    cout << "\n Per capita income :";
    cin >> c[i].income;

  }

char ch = 'y';
char cap[30];
int flag = 0;
cin.ignore();
cout << "\n Enter Capital name : ";
cin.getline(cap, 30);

  for(int k=0; k<3 ; k++)
  {
     flag = 0;
     if(strcmp(c[k].capital,cap)==0)
     {
        flag = 1;
     }
     if(flag==1)
     {
        cout<< "\n" << c[k].country << "\t" << c[k].capital << "\t" << c[k].income << "\n\n" ;
     }
  }
char con[30];
cout << "\n Enter Country name : ";
cin.getline(con,30);
  for(int m=0; m<3 ; m++)
  {
     flag = 0;
     if(strcmp(c[m].country,con)==0)
     {
        flag = 1;
     }
     if(flag==1)
     {
        cout  << c[m].capital << "\t" << c[m].income << "\n" ;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should really get a newer compiler

Comment: @Nazar554 I know friend but I am am bounded with Turbo C++ compiler. God help me..

Answer (score 0):

Combining `cin.operator<<` and `getline` results in strange behavior.  So, this code should be changed

```
cout << "\n Country's capital :";
cin.getline(c[i].capital,30);

cout << "\n Per capita income :";
cin >> c[i].income;
```

Possibly to

```
cout << "\n Country's capital :";
cin.getline(c[i].capital,30);

char buf[50]; //I don't know how long your floats are
cout << "\n Per capita income :";
cin.getline(buf);
c[i].income = atof(buf);  //#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: did you saw the code properly income is float data type and I suppose getline() is not for numeric values.

Comment: I think still you did not got my point. Line which you are trying to correct are perfectly working. Problem is here at the below `char con[30];
cout << "\n Enter Country name : ";
cin.getline(con,30);` if you are saying problem is with `cin >> c[i].income;` then how these are working `char cap[30];
int flag = 0;
cin.ignore();
cout << "\n Enter Capital name : ";
cin.getline(cap, 30);` just above the problematic code

Comment: @user1357093 Right, because you used `>>` before using `getline`.  If you absolutely want to use both together, you will probably need to look for a post explaining what needs to be done in-between each call to get the behavior working correctly, I've always opted to just avoid it.